# $A \times \{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $B \times \{x\}$, where $x \in X$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A, B ⊂ X$ be two subspaces of $X$. If A is homeomorphic to B. Then $A \times \{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $B \times \{x\}$, where $x \in X$.

How do I prove that? Is there any general theory?

Comment: The general theory is... :) a functor sends isomorphic objects to isomorphic objects.

Comment: Can u help me to prove the OP

Comment: @barto Just like to prove is the opposite of to obfuscate.

Comment: @ramram Take a homeomorphism $f:A\to B$. Define $F:A\times \{x\}\to B\times \{x\}$ by $F(a,x)=(f(a),x)$. Show that this has inverse $F^{-1}(b,x)=(f^{-1}(b),x)$. Show that both are continuous: Take $U\subset A\times\{x\}$. Then $U=\emptyset$ or $U=u\times\{x\}$ for some open $u\subset A$. Then $F(U)=\emptyset$ or $=f(u)\times\{x\}$, which is open since $f$ is homeo. And do the other direction similarly.

Comment: You are a bad, bad [wo]man, @barto.  I love it.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Since $A$ and $B$  are homeomorphic a homeomorphism $f:A\to B$ exists.

Now prove that the function $g:A\times\{x\}\to B\times\{x\}$ prescribed by $\langle a,x\rangle\mapsto\langle f(a),x\rangle$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: prove that $A\times\{x\}$ is homeomorphic to $A$, via an obvious map.

Comment: $a:\rightarrow (a, x)$

Comment: @ramram Yes; then composing homeomorphisms yields a homeomorphism.